# Switch Database model EDMX in Entity framework in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

I generated EDMX model by Visual studio and i get connection string

```
    <add name="TuttyPOSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelTuttyPOS.csdl|res://*/ModelTuttyPOS.ssdl|res://*/ModelTuttyPOS.msl;provider=Npgsql;provider connection string=&quot;Host=localhost;Port=5433;Database=TuttyPOS;Username=postgres&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>



public partial class TuttyPOSEntities : DbContext
{
    public TuttyPOSEntities()
        : base("name=TuttyPOSEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<user> users { get; set; }
}
```

I need switch between different databases with same schema by connection string in settings file (change provider connection string). How can i do this?

Comment: If you are using the same server Than just change the database name : Database=TuttyPOS

Comment: Switch when? While running the application?

Comment: You can pass connection string to dbcontext ctor. Which should be in a using around all db access. So you can change connection string every database access if you wanted.

Comment: I need switch database in runtime when the user define Database name, password, port and userid. The connection string is save in app.config. How can i change this connection string?